# Java Hibernate - Making multiple threads run simultaneously

Tags: java, hibernate

I am trying to test my SPRING MVC service performance by calling below method from multiple threads. The method uses Hibernate to fetch a record and then update it again. 
But it seems that all threads are executing sequentially, not in parallel.

**My Service Method**

```
@Transactional
public String performOperation() {
     USER user = dao.findUsr("name");
     user.setMarks(50);
}
```

**My Test App**

```
*Round 1*
thread1.start() : For Only T1, It takes time to execute : 5 Sec

*Round 2*
thread1.start()
thread2.start() : With T1 and T2: 10 Sec

*Round 3*
thread1.start()
thread2.start()
thread3.start() : With T1, T2, T3: 15 sec

*Round 4*
thread1.start()
thread2.start()
thread3.start()
thread4.start() : With T1, T2, T3, T4: 20 sec
```

**My Configuration**

```
jdbc.initial.pool.size=10
jdbc.min.pool.size=10
jdbc.max.pool.size=120
```

*Not set anything for below settings*: So taking default values for it

```
- current_session_context_class
- cache
```

Observation: Even for loop of 5000 per thread, max DB pool size utilized is 25. As observed in MySQL Dashboard

**Problem**
If you see its not executing in parallel. Hibernate is locking the row I guess. Can you provide any pointers to run it simultaneously.

Comment: In your example, you are updating single row as the only action (well you are reading it aswell, but that's hardly worth mentioning, because row is locked). There is no way to do that in parallel, which is why you do not gain any performance using additional threads

Comment: Thx for the reply.  Just wanted to add one main point, in my method, findUsr("name"), the name is always different. So all threads are working on different rows. If i start 4 threads , all if them are having different names, so different rows are selected. I can see the rows are updated randomly in db,  but the overall time required for execution is increasing in sequential order. Using mysql db,  just for info

Comment: Anybody, any comments on this; do we require any setting in Hibernate or MYSQL for this ?

Comment: Example that you have provided is not complete and does not describe the problem. Your issue is most likely caused by invalid configuration. While configuration is not visible, pin pointing the cause is impossible

Comment: Updated the config details above. Do let me know if any other details are required.

Answer (score 0):

To start the threads at exactly the same time i would recommend giving [CyclicBarrier](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CyclicBarrier.html) a try.

CyclicBarrier is "A synchronization aid that allows a set of threads to all wait for each other to reach a common barrier point".

Within that Doc is an example of how it works and runs. Make reference to that within your code. For example:

```
final CyclicBarrier gate = new CyclicBarrier(5);

Thread thread1 = new Thread(){
public void run(){
    gate.await(); // Waits until all parties have invoked await on this barrier.
    //Your Code    
}};
Thread thread2 = new Thread(){
public void run(){
    gate.await();
    //Your Code    
}};
Thread thread3 = new Thread(){
public void run(){
    gate.await();
    //Your Code    
}};
Thread thread4 = new Thread(){
public void run(){
    gate.await();
    //Your Code    
}};

thread1.start();
thread2.start();
thread3.start();
thread4.start();
gate.await();
```

Comment: Thx for thr reply fluffy.  But the problem is at server side,  the client side is just a simulator for stress tests. Need to know why my rows are locked inspite of different rows selected